# Scrapy spiders drastically slows down while running on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, scrapy, scrapyd

I am using scrapy to scrape multiple sites and Scrapyd to run spiders.

I had written 7 spiders and each spider processes at least 50 start URLs. I have around 7000 URL's. 1000 URL's for each spider.

As I start placing jobs in ScrapyD with 50 start URL's per job. Initially all spiders responds fine but suddenly they start working really slow. While running those on localhost it gives high performance.

While I run Scrapyd on localhost it gives me very high performance. As I publish jobs on Scrapyd server. Request response time drastically decreases.

Response time for each start URL is really slow after some time on server

Settings looks like this:

```
BOT_NAME = 'service_scraper'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['service_scraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'service_scraper.spiders'

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 30

# DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 1000


ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'service_scraper.pipelines.MongoInsert': 300,
}

MONGO_URL="mongodb://xxxxx:yyyy"


EXTENSIONS = {'scrapy.contrib.feedexport.FeedExporter': None}


HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
```

We tried changing `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` and `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN`, but nothing is working. We had hosted scrapyd in AWS EC2.

Comment: What EC2 Instance Type are you using? What do the CloudWatch metrics for CPU and Network look like?

Comment: I am using t2-small instance. Maximum CPU utilization is 60 percent. Network in maximum is 1,500,000. Maximum Network out is 1,500,000.

Comment: Have you considered using a larger instance type? It not only adds CPU and memory, it also adds more networking bandwidth.

Comment: Currently i had  to crawl not more then 7000 - 10000 URL's.  Even my laptop configuration Intel® Core™ i5 with 4 GM RAM is running scrapy faster then t2-small while testing with 7000 urls

Comment: Have you tested with the MongoDB pipeline?

Comment: Yes it is working fine both on server and local system

Comment: @RakeshBhatt meet the same problem, any solution?

Answer (score 1):

As with all performance testing, the goal is to find the **performance bottleneck**. This typically falls to one (or more) of:

- **Memory:** Use `top` to measure memory consumption. If too much memory is consumed, it might swap to disk, which is slower than RAM. Try adding memory.
- **CPU:** Use Amazon CloudWatch to track CPU. Be *very careful* with `t2` instances (see below).
- **Disk speed:** If the job is disk-intensive, or if memory is swapping to disk, this can impact performance -- especially for databases. Amazon EBS is network-attached disk, so network speed can actually throttle disk speed.
- **Network speed:** Due to the multi-tenant design of Amazon EC2, network bandwidth is intentionally throttled. The amount of network bandwidth available depends upon the **instance type** used.

You are using a `t2.small` instance. It has:

- **Memory:** 2GB (This is less than the 4GB on your own laptop)
- **CPU:** The `t2` family is extremely powerful, but the `t2.small` only receives an average **20% of CPU** (see below).
- **Network:** The `t2.small` is rated as **Low to Moderate** network bandwidth.

The fact that your CPU is recording 60%, while the `t2.small` is limited to an average 20% of CPU indicates that the instance is consuming CPU credits faster than they are being earned. This leads to an **eventual exhaustion of CPU credits**, thereby limiting the machine to 20% of CPU. This is highly likely to be impacting your performance. You can view CPU Credit balances in Amazon CloudWatch.

See: [T2 Instances documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html) for an understanding of CPU Credits.

**Network bandwidth** is relatively low for the `t2.small`. This impacts Internet access and communication with the Amazon EBS storage volume. Given that your application is downloading lots of web pages in parallel, and then writing them to disk, this is also a potential bottleneck for your system.

**Bottom line:** When comparing to the performance on your laptop, the instance in use has less **memory**, potentially less **CPU** due to exhaustion of CPU credits and potentially slower **disk access** due to high network traffic.

I recommend you **use a larger instance type** to confirm that performance is improved, then **experiment with different instance types** (both in the `t2` family and outside of it) to determine what size machine gives you the best price/performance trade-off.

Continue to **monitor** the CPU, Memory and Network performance to identify the leading bottleneck, then aim to fix that bottleneck.

Comment: I have tried with m4.large system but even it is not giving me appropriate results which i am looking for no improvements in performancel. As you said network bandwidth consumption could be an issue. Memory is not an issue i have 50 GB EBS volume mounted on t2-small instance. Scrapy is claimed to be working very fast. I have my previous crawling experiences on other frameworks java or nodejs hosted on AWS and Scrapy seems to be more slower